# No thermal pad.What to do now?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, overheating

Years ago my bro gave me a laptop which had a heat problem. After one day I found it was because vent was blocked, so I cleaned it. Since then it started working without shutting down but it still used get hot. So I removed heat sink and found this.

[image]

I removed those things over the chips and put it back now the CPU temp is around 40° but the graphic card is over 80°. So I turned it off. Is there any alternative to those rubber like pads? If I start my laptop will it damage my GPU?

Comment: Your laptop required the thermal pad you removed to keep the system cool. You won't be able to use the GPU since your unable to keep it cool. You might be able to order a replacement thermal pad or do some research and see what you should replace it with.  Without the thermal pad the heatsink cannot do its job.

Comment: Will putting coin between heat sink and GPU works?

Comment: That will not work. The point of a thermal pad or thermal paste is that it's elastic and the pressure will make it sit tightly against a big surface. A coin is not elastic and will both provide poor conductivity because of the uneven contact surface, and will likely crack the GPU chip if you apply any kind of pressure.

Comment: @us3r - If you placed a coin between the GPU and the heatsink the coin would permanently damage your hardware.

Comment: note, these pads are not rubber-like in reality (though they do feel a little rubbery). rubber has a very very high thermal impedance, making it a great insulator and a very very bad conductor for moving heat out of the chip. it would be like putting your chip in a winter coat. a coin is also a poor choice as others have mentioned, because it takes in more heat than it puts out per second, so it would fry your cpu in short order. Also, be sure to clean all the surfaces, removing any thermal paste or adhesive from both the cpu and the heatsink before trying to install anything new.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy wads of thermal pad, from which you can cut your own fitting your needs. Measure how thick they have to be, and then find as close a fit as you can from a vendor of your choice. For example [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=thermal%20pad) has a variety on offer.

Also, if you can't find a perfect fit: go for a little thicker rather than a little thinner. They're quite flexible, so your better bet is to squish a thicker one rather than leaving air in between.

Comment: It is hard to find in this place(India), I didnt found anything on online..shop retailers mistaken me for cooling pad. I will have try hard  for this...

Comment: try searching for 'thermal adhesive pad' (adhesive seems to get rid of the cooling plates). also if you have a brick n' mortar computer shop nearby, you can probably find a cheap pc heatsink that comes with one. you spend a little more, but if you can't find the part anywhere else....

Comment: @us3r - You could look up "thermal paste" too, one of the best is: "Arctic Silver 5".  When you apply it, however, you only do a small drop (not a glob).

Comment: @us3r, try this http://www.ebay.in/sch/i.html?_trksid=p4340.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.Xgino+thermal+pad&_nkw=gino+thermal+pad&_sacat=0&_from=R40

Answer (score -1):

There is also a thermal paste you can use instead of thermal pads. It's name is [K5-PRO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K04D3UK). It is the only one I know that can replace thermal pads. I've used it for a couple of years now on my laptops and it does wonders. Has anyone else tried it? 
There are also some videos you check out if you want on youtube in case you don't know how to replace the pads.

Here is also a link to a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njVb-8of6lY) it is use in.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: funny, that video is like icing a cake.